# vim powerline in windows 7

Tags: windows, vim, vim-powerline

I am trying to install VIM Powerline on window, I found a comment which supposed to fix how it looks in Windows, but encoding of the comment is broken by itself...

[The link to the blog post.](http://codejury.com/consolas-font-in-vim-powerline-windows/)

```
I had the same problem on windows. As an alternative to editing “vim-powerline-develop\autoload\Powerline\Functions.vim”, you can also add this to your vimrc:

    let g:Powerline_mode_V=”V·LINE
    let g:Powerline_mode_cv=”V·BLOCK”
    let g:Powerline_mode_S=”S·LINE”
    let g:Powerline_mode_cs=”S·BLOCK”
```

I don't know how to type the `cdot` operator in my keyboard (sorry for the name, I guess I am too much into Latex ...).
So, what am I supposed to do to make VIM behave under windows?

Comment: You should replace the `”` with `"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the *middle dot*, the easiest and pragmatic way would be just pasting it from the clipboard.

For direct text entry, you can enter by the character encoding's numerical value: `<C-v>183`, see `:help i_CTRL-V_digit`. On Windows, you often need to use `<C-q>` instead of `<C-v>`.

Vim also has a feature called *digraphs* for quick entry of special characters. The middle dot would be `<C-k>.M`.

For any of these to work, your text encoding must support the non-ASCII character. Best use a value of

```
:set encoding=utf-8
```

and ensure that your `~/.vimrc` is UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: Also, `<C-k>.6` is a bigger central dot